# load html with webpack

Tags: jquery, ajax, webpack, load

Im using webpack and i have to load html content from another html file in to lightbox when it opens. Im using simple lightbox-plugin.

Here is my js file

At the moment its cloning content in the lightbox but i want it to fetch it from another html

```
      var $ = require('jquery');
      var View = require('jquery-simple-view');


      require('simple-lightbox');

      module.exports = View.extend({

      initialize: function(options) {

           $.simpleLightbox.open({

        content: $('.loginModal').clone(),
        elementClass: 'slbContentEl'
    });
   }

  });
```

What im i doing wrong? thanks